# Script or tool for client-side logging

Tags: javascript, html, logging

Is there any complete solution for client-side logging? I need this tool or script to collect information about user actions (interaction with controls as clicks, form submits, using inputs...) and send it to the server.
Our system is closed web-based corporate solution, so, we can't use any public statistics solutions.

Comment: Why question is downvoted?? Explain this, dear downvoter.

Comment: Client side validation, logging etc are insecure, unless in your case, it is private. Some elements here don`t read carefully, and probably someone missed that last part.

Comment: did you hover over the downvote arrow? It says "this question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could consider implementing a heatmap.

For a start, take a look at this one from from [Labs' Media](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html)

And [this](http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?3,31481) jQuery plugin which you could tweak as per your requirement.

Comment: Lol.. somebody marked this answer -1 too.  Could you at least state your reasons, please.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm ajax?

Just send messages of client actions to an ajax script which could then post messages to the server which you could then log.

Comment: Who marked this as '-1'?? This is normal solution.

Answer (score 0):

**No plugins anwser**:
Upon html 4 there is no client-side loggin tools, except for the use of cookies as a loggin method.
With the new html 5 there are more new ways to persist data on client-side including DBs
but keep in mind that all the presisted data is sandoxed to the browser, and under strict rules like "same policie origin" and others. So do not expect to write to specific files with javascript nor in html 4 or 5.

**Using plugins**:
On the other hand if you can use plugins in your solution, many things can be done, but it is plugin specific. The best I recommend to you is greasemonekey and its variants, as it is widely accepted.